# Randomize/shuffle order of Firestore stream in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, spotify-app

I'm creating an app that makes use of a stream builder, pulling data from Firestore cloud. Here is the code:

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  appBar: appBar,
  drawer: Sidebar(),
  body: Center(
    child: StreamBuilder(
      stream: stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(
            "Loading...",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return GridView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: globals.gridCountValue != null ? globals.gridCountValue : 2,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]);
            },
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    // onPressed: () => shuffleAlbums(),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.shuffle),
    elevation: 2,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
);
```

_buildList:

```
  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    if (document.data != null) {
      return new AlbumTile(data: document.data);
    }
  }
```

I was able to shuffle the order of the list when I was using a hard-coded list of albums, but now that I'm using a stream builder, I don't know how to reach that result. I basically want to re-order the list in a random order, on the press of a button.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve shuffling functionality for a list coming from a stream.

One of them would be using the `bloc` pattern (which is basically dividing UI from Business logic), where you add another stream (let's call it `list stream`) that listens to the Firestore stream (because from what I know, the data from the Firestore stream is immutable) and when the user presses the button, you just get the data from the `list stream`, shuffle it, and push it back to the `list stream`.
In this way, you can still use the `StreamBuilder` to display the data.
If you want to learn more about the `bloc` pattern, you can read more here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4074597-getting-started-with-the-bloc-pattern (not my website)

Or you could have a variable (an array essentially) inside your `Widget` that listens to the changes coming from the Firestore stream and update the UI based on that variable. And on button pressed, shuffle the variable and reset state again.